# Formatting values of plot axis

Tags: plot, octave

I have produced two pngs of the same size with the command:

```
figure; plot(...);
print('-dpng', 'plotname1', '-S500,360');
figure; plot(...);
print('-dpng', 'plotname2', '-S500,360');
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, these images aren't aligned (the first one is "wider").

Is it possible to set the format of numbers in the y-axis? I would like to force the y-axis to use, for example, always only *1 digit* base thus removing values like "2.5e-13" in favor of "3e-13" or "2e-13".

(The x-axis is a bit ugly now, but it's not a problem since I will print these plots wider eventually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the tick marks to use on the y axis, for example:

```
set(gca, 'YTick', 0:1e-13:3e-13)
```

but you need to know the minimum, maximum and spacing you want to use.

Comment: Thank you, I used a different YTick array just for the plots that were giving problems. I also edited your answer a bit.